# Using system commands with echo in bash file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement, echo

I have been searching through forums for a fix to this, but everything I encounter is way out of my league atm or doesn't fix my issue. What i'm trying to do is pretty basic, but can't seem to get it to work in unix. I'm currently working on a bash script in unix, and I can't get if statements and echo commands to work.

Trying to get if statements to run system commands inside of them and every time I get an error where the command is not found. (ie: whoami: command not found.)
Same problem with the echo command as well. (ie: w: command not found.) I know these commands will work because I can throw them into the command line and they return the values i'm looking for.

```
function userprocess {
if [[ $(whoami | grep $EUIDS) = $EUIDS ]]
then
        echo -e "==> Active processes for $EUIDS \050 Logged in \0051:"
        echo "$(w -h $EUIDS)"
else
        echo -e  "==> Active processes for $EUIDS \0050 NOT logged in \0051:"
        echo "$(w -h $EUIDS)"
fi
}
```

I've tried this

```
function userprocess {
if [[ ${command[whoami | grep $EUIDS]} = $EUIDS ]]
then
        echo -e "==> Active processes for $EUIDS \050 Logged in \0051:"
        echo ${command[w -h $EUIDS]}
else
        echo -e  "==> Active processes for $EUIDS \0050 NOT logged in \0051:"
        echo ${command[w -h $EUIDS]}
fi
}
```

and this...

```
function userprocess {
if [[ 'whoami | grep $EUIDS' = $EUIDS ]]
then
        echo -e "==> Active processes for $EUIDS \050 Logged in \0051:"
        echo 'w -h $EUIDS'
else
        echo -e  "==> Active processes for $EUIDS \0050 NOT logged in \0051:"
        echo 'w -h $EUIDS'
fi
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Sometimes I get the right output only to get an error token that is equal to $EUIDS. I'm at the end of my rope, and I need a lifeline to get this done.

Comment: What kind of Unix? What shell are you using? You're using Bash syntax, but are you sure this is running under bash?

In general, when you `echo` a command, it just prints exactly what you put in quotes to the terminal. The right way to run the commands and show the output would be to just `w -h $EUIDS`, not `echo "echo $(w -h $EUIDS)"` or  `echo 'w -h $EUIDS'`.

Comment: ok bash version 4.2.25 GNU bash and not sure the unix version (maybe i686-pc-linux-gnu) and putting just w -h $EUIDS gives me error w: command not recognised. Also using the include of #! /bin/bash

Comment: Found unix version to be 3.2.0-97-generic #137-Ubuntu

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to do (there might be a better way), but as a rule of thumb: in `Bash`, single quotes `''` don't escape anything, so use double quotes whenever you want to do things like `echo "w -h $EUIDS"`. Regarding the `if`, why don't you try this: `if [ "$(whoami | grep $EUIDS)" = "$EUIDS" ]; then ...`

Comment: Ok so tried `echo "w -h $EUIDS"` and it prints it to the screen, but does not run the command. and the if statement `if [ "$(whoami | grep $EUIDS)" = "$EUIDS" ]` still gets me the error whoami: command not found. Just to be clear, the file convention should be .sh if i'm correct? Just trying to see if i've got everything beyond the file done correctly. Could it be a chmod issue?

Comment: @fanton Huh? Single quotes protect everything between them; you could say it's the ultimate escape.

Comment: That's Linux not Unix.

Comment: Ah so the root of the problem is that i'm using unix commands then? Need to run linux commands. I'll look to see if there are differences in these (as i'm sure there are).

Comment: Your first attempt looks roughly correct; the second is outlandish, and the third uses single quotes where it looks like you meant backticks, but `$(whoami)` syntax is much superior anyway. The `command not found` sounds like you are messing up the value of `PATH` elsewhere in your script. Always use lowercase for your variable names to avoid stomping on system variables.

Comment: Linux and Unix are basically equivalent for this discussion. It is technically true that Linux is not a Unix kernel but the kernel is completely irrelevant here anyway.

Comment: Ok will do on lowercase. Now for the PATH, should PATH be something that i need to set other than `#! /bin/bash`? I've looked at the `which` command on a lot of the commands i'm using, and most are in `/usr/bin` or `/bin/`

Comment: For these commands, the default `PATH` should be fine.

Comment: You should simply use `command` instead of `echo "$(command)"` - capturing what the command prints so you can print it yourself is completely redundant.

Comment: AH sweet jesus it was the damn uppercase lettering in some of the variables. Went through the script and turned all variables to lowercase, and viola! Over writing PATH was the issue. Ok so for a novice user, why the hell are most of the bash tutorials coded with uppercase variable names? Thanks a million, and i'll put up the fix.

Comment: See here for a quick demo: http://ideone.com/G5OkeE (though the fact that the first `whoami` fails there, in a different way, is slightly distracting).

Answer (score 0):

Alright so the issue was not the syntax of the code, but of the variable names. Most of my variable names were in UPPERCASE, which caused such things as PATH to be over-written. 
For example:

```
PATH=$(pwd)
```

This will over-write.
You need to do this:

```
path=$(pwd)
```

And the correct syntax for the code snippet is this:

```
function userprocess {
if [ "$(users | grep -c $euids)" = "$euids" ]
then
        echo -e "==> Active processes for $euids \050 Logged in \0051:"
        w -h $euids
else
        echo -e  "==> Active processes for $euids \0050 NOT logged in \0051:"
        w -h $euids
fi
}
```

Thanks to all for your input on this issue! Cheers!

Comment: You still should not use `echo $(stuff)` unless you specifically want the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the output from the command `stuff`. Simply running a command will produce its output just fine.